# Critera for "horse-racing" normally-distributed estimators?

Tags: confidence-interval, model-selection, estimators, efficiency

I am seeking to compare how two estimators perform on a test set.  These estimators are approximately normal -- they produce both point estimates and $\alpha$ intervals.

One would like the point estimate to be very close to the true value, but one would also like the interval to cover the true value at the nominal rate.  More to the point, one would like the interval to be as narrow as possible without being wrong.

What are some good ways of summarizing this sort of information?

For a single point, I was thinking of comparing the desnity of the normal under the true value.  For example, say the true value is 1, and I have two estimates from two estimators -- one that is a standard normal, and one that is $\mathcal{N}(.5, 2)$.

```
g <- seq(-5, 5, .1)
plot(g, dnorm(g), type = 'l', col = 'red')
lines(g, dnorm(g, mean = .5, sd = 2), type = 'l', col = 'blue')
abline(v = 1)
```

[image]

```
dnorm(1, mean = 0, sd = 1)
[1] 0.2419707
dnorm(1, mean = .5, sd = 2)
[1] 0.1933341
```

By this logic, the red estimator would be better, even though the point estimate is farther away than the blue estimator.

Say I had another point whose true value was -4, and the intervals for that example took the following form:

```
plot(g, dnorm(g, sd = 3), type = 'l', col = 'red')
lines(g, dnorm(g, mean = -.5, sd = 4), type = 'l', col = 'blue')
abline(v = -4)
```

[image]

```
dnorm(-4, mean = 0, sd = 3)
0.05467002
dnorm(-4, mean = -.5, sd = 4)
0.06801375
```

Here blue is better.

The result is similarly intuitive, but the scales are different.  If I want to combine information about the estimators as applied to the first and second point, the result from the first would dominate that from the second.  I'm not sure that this approach would hold up when comparing hundreds/thousands/millions of points.

This approach that I've proposed is something that I just thought of.  Are there established ways of asking this sort of question?  What heading(s) do they fall under?  (i.e.: what should I google?)

Note: the estimators that I'm working with are probably biased in finite samples.  I'm interested in finite-sample performance of certain estimators on a particular problem, and theory is good if it doesn't rely on asymptotics.